# How to improve graph centrality calculation parallel performance?

Tags: performance, graph, parallel-processing, julia

I am getting performance degradation after parallelizing the code that is calculating graph centrality. Graph is relatively large, 100K vertices. Single threaded application take approximately 7 minutes. As recommended on julialang site (http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#man-parallel-computing) I adapted code and used pmap api in order to parallelize calculations. I started calculation with 8 processes (julia -p 8 calc_centrality.jl). To my surprise I got 10 fold slow down. Parallel process now take more than hour. I noticed that it take several minutes for parallel process to initialize and starts calculation. Even after all 8 CPUs are %100 busy with julia app, calculation is super slow.

Any suggestion how to improve parallel performance is appreciated.

calc_centrality.jl :

```
using Graphs
require("read_graph.jl")
require("centrality_mean.jl")

function main()
    file_name = "test_graph.csv"
    println("graph creation: ", file_name)
    g = create_generic_graph_from_file(file_name)
    println("num edges: ", num_edges(g))
    println("num vertices: ", num_vertices(g))

    data = cell(8)
    data[1] = {g, 1, 2500}
    data[2] = {g, 2501, 5000}
    data[3] = {g, 5001, 7500}
    data[4] = {g, 7501, 10000}
    data[5] = {g, 10001, 12500}
    data[6] = {g, 12501, 15000}
    data[7] = {g, 15001, 17500}
    data[8] = {g, 17501, 20000}
    cm = pmap(centrality_mean, data)
    println(cm)

end
println("Elapsed: ", @elapsed main(), "\n")
```

centrality_mean.jl

```
using Graphs

function centrality_mean(gr, start_vertex)
    centrality_cnt = Dict()
    vertex_to_visit = Set()
    push!(vertex_to_visit, start_vertex)

    cnt = 0
    while !isempty(vertex_to_visit)
        next_vertex_set = Set()
        for vertex in vertex_to_visit
            if !haskey(centrality_cnt, vertex)
                centrality_cnt[vertex] = cnt
                for neigh in out_neighbors(vertex, gr)
                    push!(next_vertex_set, neigh)
                end
            end
        end
        cnt += 1
        vertex_to_visit = next_vertex_set
    end
    mean([ v for (k,v) in centrality_cnt ])
end

function centrality_mean(data::Array{})
    gr = data[1]
    v_start = data[2]
    v_end = data[3]
    n = v_end - v_start + 1;
    cm = Array(Float64, n)
    v = vertices(gr)
    cnt = 0
    for i = v_start:v_end
        cnt += 1
        if cnt%10 == 0
            println(cnt)
        end
        cm[cnt] = centrality_mean(gr, v[i])
    end
    return cm
end
```

Comment: I think we would need to see some code to diagnose the problem. Do you have it hosted somewhere accessible (i.e. Github  or gist)?

Comment: take al look at the code

Comment: That's a lot of graph moving/copying.  How about using a `DArray` or `SharedArray` containing your graph or defining `@everywhere g = ...`?  Then you won't need to specify `g` in your `pmap` call.

Comment: Is your `centrality_mean` the same as the mean of the non-Inf row values of `floyd_warshall(distance_matrix(g,ones(g.nedges)))`?  If so, how is it's performance?

Comment: I modified code for centrality_mean from https://gist.github.com/SirVer/3353761. In essence centrality mean is special case, distances between vertices are equal, of closeness centrality explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality

Comment: So, does the mean of the non-Inf row values of `floyd_warshall(distance_matrix(g,ones(g.nedges)))` calculate the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code with @everywhere suggested in comments by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374/rickhg12hs. That fixed performance issue!!!

test_parallel_pmap.jl

```
using Graphs
require("read_graph.jl")
require("centrality_mean.jl")

function main()
   @everywhere file_name = "test_data.csv"
   println("graph creation from: ", file_name)
   @everywhere data_graph = create_generic_graph_from_file(file_name)
   @everywhere data_graph_vertex = vertices(data_graph)
   println("num edges: ", num_edges(data_graph))
   println("num vertices: ", num_vertices(data_graph))

   range = cell(2)
   range[1] = {1, 25000}
   range[2] = {25001, 50000}
   cm = pmap(centrality_mean_pmap, range)
   for i = 1:length(cm)
       println(length(cm[i]))
  end
end

println("Elapsed: ", @elapsed main(), "\n")
```

centrality_mean.jl

```
using Graphs

function centrality_mean(start_vertex::ExVertex)
    centrality_cnt = Dict{ExVertex, Int64}()
    vertex_to_visit = Set{ExVertex}()
    push!(vertex_to_visit, start_vertex)

    cnt = 0
    while !isempty(vertex_to_visit)
        next_vertex_set = Set()
        for vertex in vertex_to_visit
            if !haskey(centrality_cnt, vertex)
                centrality_cnt[vertex] = cnt
                for neigh in out_neighbors(vertex, data_graph)
                    push!(next_vertex_set, neigh)
                end
            end
        end
       cnt += 1
       vertex_to_visit = next_vertex_set
    end
    mean([ v for (k,v) in centrality_cnt ])
end

function centrality_mean(v_start::Int64, v_end::Int64)
    n = v_end - v_start + 1;
    cm = Array(Float64, n)
    cnt = 0
    for i = v_start:v_end
        cnt += 1
        cm[cnt] = centrality_mean(data_graph_vertex[i])
    end
    return cm
end

function centrality_mean_pmap(range::Array{})
    v_start = range[1]
    v_end = range[2]
    centrality_mean(v_start, v_end)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this has nothing to do with parallelism. Your second `centrality_mean` method has no clue what type of objects `gr`, `v_start`, and `v_end` are. So it's going to have to use non-optimized, slow code for that "outer loop."

While there are several potential solutions, probably the easiest is to break up your function that receives the "command" from `pmap`:

```
function centrality_mean(data::Array{})
    gr = data[1]
    v_start = data[2]
    v_end = data[3]
    centrality_mean(gr, v_start, v_end)
end

function centrality_mean(gr, v_start, v_end)
    n = v_end - v_start + 1;
    cm = Array(Float64, n)
    v = vertices(gr)
    cnt = 0
    for i = v_start:v_end
        cnt += 1
        if cnt%10 == 0
            println(cnt)
        end
        cm[cnt] = centrality_mean(gr, v[i])
    end
    return cm
end
```

All this does is create a break, and gives julia a chance to optimize the second part (which contains the performance-critical loop) for the actual types of the inputs.

Comment: I agree all methods should have proper signature. Unfortunately adding signature does not help nor restructuring code as you suggested. Adding -p option on julia start is causing the slow down (julia -p 8 calc_centrality.jl). Code is much slower even in case for -p 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Julia page on parallel computing](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/parallel-computing/):

*Julia provides a multiprocessing environment based on message passing to allow programs to run on multiple processes in separate memory domains at once.*

If I interpret this right, Julia's parallelism requires message passing to synchonize the processess.   If each individual process does only a little work, and then does a message-pass, the computation will be dominated by message-passing overhead and not doing any work.

I can't see from your code, and I don't know Julia well enough, to see where the parallelism breaks are. But you have a big complicated graph that may be spread willy-nilly across multiple processes.  If they need to interact on walking across graph links, you'll have exactly that kind of overhead.

You may be able to fix it by precomputing a partition of the graph into roughly equal size, highly cohesive regions.   I suspect that breakup requires that same type of complex graph processing that you already want to do, so you may have a chicken and egg problem to boot.

It may be that Julia offers you the wrong parallelism model.  You might want a shared address space so that threads walking the graph dont' have to use messages to traverse arcs.

Comment: My understanding is that each process should have copy of all data. In that case each process should have whole graph at disposal so inter process communication should not be a problem.

Comment: If that's the case, then each individual processor should be able to do the whole computation in the time it took the single processor to do it.  So, someplace there's an interaction.   Where is it?